# Salesforce: API to get info of all enterprise users using admins auth token?

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, metadata-api, identity

Is there a way from the SOAP/METADATA API to get the all the registered users of an enterprise using an API call with the admin's auth-token? I only require the email address, name and role of the all the enterprise users

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could either use the REST API

```
curl https://<INSTANCE>.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=SELECT+email+,+name+,+roleid+from+User -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

for details see
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_query.htm

or you can run a SOQL query against the SOAP API using your access token for the session ID

Details in the WebServices API Documentation
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_query.htm

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'depending on the number of users'? Is there a limit in case of the REST API?

Comment: not necessarily at a limit, except for the general 50k record Governor Limit. But I personally tend to use the SOAP API when working with larger record sets and programmatic requests

Comment: there is no 50k governor limit for the rest api, thats for apex.

Comment: @superfell: you are absolutely right, error in reasoning. modified the answer